# How to include vmatrix in bmatrix?

Tags: math-mode, nccmath

Here is my code for this work. But I failed to compile this.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}  
\usepackage[left=8mm,top=6mm,bottom=6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\mbox{
\Large$
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{vmatrix}
0&1\\
-1&0
\end{vmatrix}
&
\begin{vmatrix}
-2 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{vmatrix}
&
\begin{vmatrix}
-2&0\\
1&-1
\end{vmatrix}
\end{bmatrxi}
$}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have a typo: `\end{bmatrxi}`. TeX warns you about that.

Comment: @campa, Thanks Man!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was due to a simple typo (solved in a comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix a typo: change `\end{bmatrxi}` to `\end{bmatrix}`.

A separate observation: The presence of the `\mbox{\Large$...$}` chunk inside an unnumbered display-math group seems a bit idiosyncratic, to put it politely. If you need to increase the font size used in the display-math group by 44%, you should run

```
\begingroup
\Large % note that this comes before "\["
\[
% (math material)
\]
\endgroup
```

instead. The `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` statements serve to localize the scope of the `\Large` directive, which is a text-mode directive and hence should occur outside a math environment.

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath} % for definitions of 'bmatrix' and 'vmatrix' environments 

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\Large % note that this comes before "\["
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{vmatrix}  0 & 1 \\ -1 &  0 \end{vmatrix} &
\begin{vmatrix} -2 & 1 \\  1 &  0 \end{vmatrix} &
\begin{vmatrix} -2 & 0 \\  1 & -1 \end{vmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}   \qquad\mathtt{\string\ Large}
\]
\endgroup

%% back to normal font size
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{vmatrix}  0 & 1 \\ -1 &  0 \end{vmatrix} &
\begin{vmatrix} -2 & 1 \\  1 &  0 \end{vmatrix} &
\begin{vmatrix} -2 & 0 \\  1 & -1 \end{vmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}   \qquad\mathtt{\string\ normalsize}
\]
\end{document}
```